# Implementing Volume Control

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, core-audio

I need to implement a volume control for an app. I have no idea where to start because the docs on CoreAudio aren't great in number, and I'm a beginner with this.

Does anyone have a reference (other than the Apple Docs) or example?

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial has an example on how to create a volume control within the tutorial:

[Playing Audio on an iPhone using AVAudioPlayer (iOS 4)](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Playing_Audio_on_an_iPhone_using_AVAudioPlayer_%28iOS_4%29)

To reference search for this component:

```
UISlider *volumeControl;
```

Good luck!

Comment: you can use this to add a slider (cocos2d): http://srooltheknife.blogspot.com/2011/01/creating-slider-control-in-cocos2d.html

And this for the volume control: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/13671



You'll need to look through the responses but the code you want is: [CDAudioManager sharedManager].backgroundMusic.volume